# How to include appcompat_v7 in Android.mk file

Tags: android

I want my app to be built with Android Source code. How to include appcompat_v7 in Android.mk file and where to place the appcompat_v7 folder in source code. I am using the following code,

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \appcompat_v7
# Include all java files.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyPackage
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

I am getting error

> make: No rule to make target 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/\appcompat_v7_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyPackage_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'.  Stop.

Anyone Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to build a package that includes appcompat using the following Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MySuperAwesomeApp

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-gridlayout
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v13

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/gridlayout/res

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.gridlayout

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/android-5.0.1_r1/Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, and I hope it can help! Copy the jar files in the libs of appcompat_v7 project to the libs directory of your project.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
        android-support-v4 \
        android-support-v7-appcompat
        <more jar could be added here>

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := <The name of your App project>

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += <The absolute path to your appcompat_v7 project>/res

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages   android.support.v4:android.support.v7.appcompat <replace the _ with . for your all jar files>

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Actually, the appcompat_v7 project is created to make the project compatible with older version of SDK. So to avoid generating this project automatically, you could set minimum requirement of SDK version to higher than 4.0 when you create your own Android project.

Answer (score 0):

I built my package in command line along with Android source code and had hard time to include the v7 appcompat. To me, copying android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to libs and changing Android.mk as others posted above did not solve my problem. I finally figured out that I need build that v7 appcompat first.

1. Go to PATH/TO/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat and build it first.
2. No need to copy appcompat.jar to libs. Make your Android.mk like two posts above and it should work.