# AOSP Project compilation error. Module with resources

Tags: android, android-source

I am developing application for Android Open Source Project (custom OS). I also have 1 module which consists of java files and resources files as well, which I use for project. When I try to compile it, it says No Resources found for the values I have used in my module's res folder. Any solution?

Library uses

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

}

I am using seekbar's style custom as follows :

```
<style name="IXMSeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
...
```

But while compilation, it says no resources found

---

In other words, I have a hello world application, using dependency of module. How to deploy that project for my Custom OS?

Comment: did you add your module in `setting.gradle`?

Comment: @HemantParmar In settings.gradle I have I have "include ':app', ':CustomLibrary'"

Comment: so getting not found issue in CustomLibrary ?

Comment: It compiles in android studio, but when I compile it for AOSP using commands, it gives error. Is there anything to be written in Android.mk for android support v7?

Comment: not getting to much but have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667564/5110595) hope it will help you.

Comment: Please show the MK you have created/or modified in order to compile with AOSP.